# File in which the data structure for Global Descriptor and Local Descriptor table is defined?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am reading [Understanding Linux Kernel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005652), and in it I read about the Global Descriptor table and the Local Descriptor Table.

In which source file(s)(of linux kernel) the data structure for GDT and LDT are defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A google search for the term "**Linux Kernel file gdt**" yields the exact results that you are looking for. [This](http://books.google.com/books?id=h0lltXyJ8aIC&pg=PT59&lpg=PT59&dq=linux%20kernel%20file%20gdt&source=bl&ots=gO0lH05fHX&sig=h4X1I6TP_P7JlEwzoCkQk3uztjw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XFwPVM-WBbOBsQTtiIDIDw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=linux%20kernel%20file%20gdt&f=false) is the link to the search result of the book with the contents describing where the GDT and LDT are defined.

- All GDTs are stored in the *cpu_gdt_table* array.
- If you look in the source code index, you can see that these symbols are defined in the file `arch/i386/kernel/head.S`. However, I think the source code index can be viewed when you have a copy of the book. But nevertheless, the file where GDT is defined is given.

Comment: This answer is outdated for the 4.* kernels as far as I can tell. The new kernels use the `asm volatile` C code instead of `head.S` assembly code. But I cannot figure out how the new kernels define these array constants.

Answer (score 2):

For the latest kernel, the GDT seems to be defined in at least 3 separate files.

- `arch/x86/include/asm/desc_defs.h`
- `arch/x86/include/asm/desc.h`
- `arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h`

The layout of the main GDT seems to be defined in `arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h` around [line 91](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h#L91). There are comments about the layout above this line.

The completed table is loaded in `arch/x86/include/asm/desc.h` with the function `static inline void native_load_gdt(const struct desc_ptr *dtr)` which just calls the assembly opcode `lgdt`. This is consistent with the way older kernels load the table into the processor. See line 303 [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/i386/kernel/head.S?h=linux-2.6.11.y#n303). However, I cannot find any calls to this function in the code base. Someone please help figure this out.

Also I cannot find the equivalent of defining the constants of the actual table as in [line 479](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/i386/kernel/head.S?h=linux-2.6.11.y#n479) in newer kernels.